# Bash: Send associative array to the function

Tags: bash, hashtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass an associative array as argument to a function in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069188/how-to-pass-an-associative-array-as-argument-to-a-function-in-bash)

I declare my hash array:

```
declare -A some_array
```

And I declare my function:

```
some_function() {
  ..
}
```

How can I send the array as an argument to the function in order to access it?

I know that I can use it as a global variable, but it's not the way out when I have a lot of hash arrays I want to use with some function.

If there is no way to do it, how can I assign to the one hash array value of other?

Answer (score 2):

Access it as a global variable (simply refer to it by name inside your function). There is no array passing in Bash. There are awkward techniques that try to do this, but I recommend avoiding the mess.

Other options include writing your entire script in a language such as Python or Perl which supports passing arrays, hashes or their references.

In Bash 4.3 or later you can use [name references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55170447/26428), but there are [caveats](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#The_problem_with_bash.27s_name_references).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The changes may be visible within the function, but are lost outside of it.

Comment: @user1167662: Did you declare the array inside the function? That makes it local to the function. If you declare it outside then it's global.

Comment: I tried inside and outside a function. I also tried `declare -gA var_name`, which I understand is supposed to make the variable have global scope, but that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: @user1167662: This snippet works as advertised: `declare -A arr; my_func () { arr['customer']=$1; }; my_func Bob; printf '%s\n' "${arr['customer']}"; declare -p arr`. Does that work for you? What version of Bash? If that doesn't work or doesn't provide clues as to what to look for in your code, then I recommend that you ask a new question and show the code you tried and what the result is and what the expected result is.