# In Bash, should I use declare instead of local and export?

Tags: bash

I've recently discovered the `declare` Bash builtin, which declares variables with local scope and can also be used to export variables or even set type.

```
# bar an baz have local scope
foo()
{
    declare bar
    local baz
}

# bing and bong are both exported
declare -x bing
export bong

# i is an integer, j is read-only integer
declare -i i=0
declare  -ri j=10
```

I've started using it everywhere and stopped using local and export. So why do `local` and `export` even exist?

Answer (score 13):

They exists because of the history. [This manual](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html) says `declare` was introduced in `bash` version 2, `local` was introduced earlier. People use `local`, `export` and `readonly` by convention and readability.

When I see `local` I think - 'Och! This must be a function local variable. I must be reading a function.'. When I see `declare` I need to scroll up until I see a function declaration, to know if i'm in a function and to see if the variable is local.

With `export`, the `export` is a POSIX builtin, so it will work everywhere, which is important. But it's similar. When I see `export` I think - 'Och! This variable is getting exported!'. When I see `declare -x` I need to refresh my memory with `declare` options (well, it's easy, `-x` sounds like `export`, but it's still one more thing to remember). I prefer writing `local` and `export`. Because it is they way my mind thinks - this variable is local, that variable is exported.

When I read scripts with only `local` and `export`, without the use of `declare`, I know it's an easy script. `declare -i` or `declare -n` can complicate things.

Also, `typeset` and `declare` are exact synonyms. So, you could also ask, why `declare`, when you can `typeset`? Probably `typeset` was introduced, so you can run `ksh` scripts using `bash` without any changes. Same with `local` and `readonly` keywords. Similar with `mapfile` and `readarray`. Convention. With a file you could  go with `mapfile`, but with a here string I sometimes go with `readarray`, because I am reading some data into an array, and not mapping the file.

I believe the `local` keyword is (a bit?) more portable then `declare`. You could read ex. [this unix.stackexchange thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493729/list-of-shells-that-support-local-keyword-for-defining-local-variables) for some more info.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases Yes! but remember using `declare` in most cases with few of its flags causes the shell to interpret them as expressions *rather* than just plain assignment strings. Assume you want to define a variable to hold integer only values with the `-i` attribute

```
declare -i x; x=2+2; echo $x
4
export x; x=2+2; echo $x
2+2
```

The shell has forced the assignment to be treated as a integer expression instead of a plain variable assignment. The `export`/`local` commands don't define this special processing to be applied to assignments.

Also the built-ins `local`/`export` were added to `bash` much earlier than the attributes which `declare` provides. POSIX does not define either `local` or `declare`, so if you were to target scripts written on a minimal `sh` shell, only `export` is available ( note that exporting a function with `-f` is still only Bash-ism and not POSIX )