# declare inside a bash funcion not working as expected with associative arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, declare, associative

I declare an associative array:

```
$ declare -A dikv
```

Initialize it with some key/value pairs:

```
$ dikv=( ["k1"]="v1" ["k2"]="v2" ["k3"]="v3" ["k4"]="v4")
```

Then I can save the contents to a file:

```
$ declare -p dikv > /tmp/dikv.saved
```

This is the content of /tmp/dikv.saved:

```
$ cat /tmp/dikv.saved
declare -A dikv=([k4]="v4" [k1]="v1" [k2]="v2" [k3]="v3" )
```

Now, in a new shell environment, I can load the saved associative array:

```
$ source /tmp/dikv.saved
```

And the content is properly accesible:

```
$ echo "${!dikv[@]}"
k4 k1 k2 k3

$ echo "${dikv[@]}"
v4 v1 v2 v3
```

This works as expected, nice.

Now I want to do exactly the same but using a bash function:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A dikv
backup_dictionary()
{
    local -n dict_ref=$1
    FILE=$2

    echo "${!dict_ref[@]}"
    echo "${dict_ref[@]}"

    declare -p dict_ref > $FILE
}

dikv=( ["k1"]="v1" ["k2"]="v2" ["k3"]="v3" ["k4"]="v4")
backup_dictionary dikv /tmp/dikv.saved
```

As you can see, I pass the associative array to the function using local -n. When I run this code, the echo's inside the function print the content of the associative array properly. So, as far as I understand, the associative array has been properly passed as argument.

However, this statement is not working as expected:

```
$ declare -p dict_ref > $FILE
```

This is the content of $FILE:

```
$ cat /tmp/dikv.saved
declare -n dict_ref="dikv"
```

I expected to see something like this:

```
dikv=( ["k1"]="v1" ["k2"]="v2" ["k3"]="v3" ["k4"]="v4")
```

As it happens when not using a bash funcion. Can you explain what happens here? And what should be the proper way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8879444/5291015

Comment: _the associative array has been properly passed as argument_  ... No. The **name** of the array has been properly passed as argument. The array itself is still global; you are accessing it indirectly via its name. Think of a pointer in C: If you pass a pointer to some data structure to a function, this does not pass the data structure itself.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for the explanation, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dict_ref` stores the string `dikv`. Hence if you do a `declare -p dict_ref`, I would expect to see as output something like

*declare -n dict_ref=dikv*

Note that dereferencing (due to the `-n` declaration) occurs during parameter expansion, i.e. when you do a `$dict_ref`.

You could do a

```
declare -p "$1" >$FILE
```